# How to count number of digits for each string in list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, count

I am trying to count the number of digits for each string in list of strings:

```
['', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '',]
```

So the expected output I would like to get is

```
[0 0 18 0 0 31 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I was thinking about using numpy count but the data type for list of strings is list so should I be using len?

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension along with the `len()` function:

```py
inp = ['', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '',]
lengths = [len(x) for x in inp]
print(lengths)  # [0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the map function to apply the built in len function to each number in the list, and then convert the map object to a list.

```
nums = ['', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '',]
lengths = list(map(len, nums))
print(lengths)
```

Output:

```
[0 0 18 0 0 31 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Your code will emit [0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] and not the output stated/required

Answer (score 1):

Use len() function along with for loop to get the count for each string inside a list. like this

```
newList = []
for value in values:

    newList.append(len(value))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If you want the output without comma, you want to add a little statements like this!

```
anotherList = []
for value in values:

    try:
        if anotherList[0] != "":
            anotherList[0] = str(anotherList[0]) + " " + str(len(value))

    except IndexError:
        anotherList.append(len(value))
```

Output:

```
['0 0 18 0 0 31 0 0 0 0 0']
```

If you want the exact output which needs to be displayed or something, you can simply use string concatenation

```
exactList = ""
for value in values:

    if exactList == "":
        exactList = str(len(value))

    else:
        exactList = str(exactList) + " " + str(len(value))
```

Output:

```
[0 0 18 0 0 31 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The get that exact output you could do this:

```
L = ['', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '',]

print(f'[{" ".join(map(str, map(len, L)))}]')
```

**Output:**

```
[0 0 18 0 0 31 0 0 0 0 0]
```